# .htaccess modified hiding url php make my input submit doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have modified my .htaccess file to hide the ending `.php` extension of the URLs, but it breaks my input submit button so login doesn't work anymore with my username and password. What's wrong with my `.htaccess` file or my php file input submit button ??

This is the code for my `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Someone can edit my question.. my english is too bad :(

Comment: Try something like `RewriteCond (.+) ^$1\.php [NC]` instead of `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]`

Comment: that can't hide php extension..

Comment: Oops my mistake. It should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]`.